# Creating a Gradle Custom Plugin with Java

Tags: java, gradle

I'm creating a build process with Gradle and I want to provide a plugin that uses Java code. The Gradle [plugin documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) *says* this is possible:

> You can implement a custom plugin in any language you like, provided the implementation ends up compiled as bytecode. For the examples here, we are going to use Groovy as the implementation language. You could use Java or Scala instead, if you want.

However, after multiple hours of Googling and reading, I have yet to find any explanation of how to create a Gradle custom plugin with Java. It seems like you could create the code for it in a directory like:

```
<rootProjectDir>/buildSrc/src/main/java/
  MyGradlePlugin.java
  MyGradleTasks.java
```

But the question then becomes:

1. How to implement the plugin class and tasks in Java to be compatible with Gradle?
2. How to get Gradle to recognize the Java classes and tasks so you can use them in a build?

   Can you just reference the plugin class like you do for the Groovy equivalent?

   **`src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins/myjavaplugin.properties`**
   `implementation-class=org.me.MyGradlePlugin`

I realize that I could just call the Java code with `project.javaexec` or `JavaExec`, but I'm concerned this will make my build process less portable.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Here's a basic, stand-alone, Java-based Gradle plugin and the steps to get it working:

1. Make sure Gradle 1.6 or higher and Java JDK is installed
2. Create these files below with the directory structure indicated
3. Change directories to the `<projectRoot>/plugin` directory
4. Execute the plugin build: `$ gradle uploadArchives` This (very important) step compiles the Java code and puts it in your local Maven repo (../repo).
5. Now execute the consumer script by changing directories to `<projectRoot>/consumer`
6. Execute the script that depends on the plugin: `$ gradle checkitout`

### Java Classes

**projectRoot/plugin/src/main/java/org/joefernandez/gradle/MyJavaPlugin.java**

```
package org.joefernandez.gradle;

import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;

public class MyJavaPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project target) {
        target.task("javaTask");
    }

}
```

**projectRoot/plugin/src/main/java/org/joefernandez/gradle/MyJavaTask.java**

```
package org.joefernandez.gradle;

import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction;

public class MyJavaTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    public void javaTask() {
        System.out.println("Hello from MyJavaTask");
    }

}
```

### Plugin Class declaration

**projectRoot/plugin/src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins/test-plugin.properties**

```
implementation-class=org.joefernandez.gradle.MyJavaPlugin
```

### Plugin Build Script

Note the *uploadArchives* task: You must run this task to make the plugin available to the consumer script.

**projectRoot/plugin/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
}

apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

group = 'org.joefernandez'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: uri('../repo'))
        }
    }
}
```

### Settings for the Plugin

**projectRoot/plugin/settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'MyJavaPlugin'
```

### Root script

**projectRoot/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
}
```

### Consumer script

**projectRoot/consumer/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url uri('../repo')
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.joefernandez',
                   name: 'MyJavaPlugin',
                version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'test-plugin'

task checkitout(type: org.joefernandez.gradle.MyJavaTask) {
    println("running consumer task!")
}
```

Comment: Specifying `repository(url: uri('../repo'))` is optional. You could instead export to the default local repo. And import from mavenLocal().

Comment: I created an Android Studio project based on Joe's descriptions at https://github.com/AttwellBrian/SamplePlugin/tree/master. Feel free to fork or copy-pasta.

Comment: Not working for me. Gradle probably changed something

Answer (score 24):

I would like to propose a few amendments to Joe's great answer.

**projectRoot/plugin/src/main/java/org/joefernandez/gradle/MyJavaPlugin.java**

This change wires the task into the supplied project without the need to sub-class it.

```
package org.joefernandez.gradle;

import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;

public class MyJavaPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project target) {
        // CHANGE HERE
        target.getTasks().create("javaTask", MyJavaTask.class);
    }

}
```

### Consumer script

**projectRoot/consumer/build.gradle**

This change removes the now unnecessary task definition

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url uri('../repo')
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.joefernandez',
                   name: 'MyJavaPlugin',
                version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'test-plugin'

// CHANGE HERE
```

This them changes step 6, to:

`Execute the script that depends on the plugin: $ gradle javaTask`

Answer (score 3):

Plugin classes must implement the `org.gradle.api.Plugin` interface. Task classes typically extend the `org.gradle.api.DefaultTask` class. It doesn't matter which (JVM) language is used for this. The Gradle codebase contains many plugin and task classes implemented in Java.

How to build and ship a plugin is another question, again mostly unrelated to which language is used. See the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) and `samples/customPlugin` in the full Gradle distribution.

Comment: Thanks, Peter! This got me on the right track. I'll post my solution shortly.