# gradle custom java plugin (with properties)

Tags: java, android, gradle

I created a custom gradle plugin shown in [Creating a Gradle Custom Plugin with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664183/creating-a-gradle-custom-plugin-with-java) and it worked very well.

Now I want to extend my plugin with parameters like

```
plugin {
   appVersion "0.1_1"
}
```

but I got errors/warnings

```
Deprecated dynamic property: "appVersion" on "com.example.gradle.task.PluginTaskExtension_Decorated@55fa0b27", value: "0.1_1".
Deprecated dynamic property "appVersion" created in multiple locations.
```

I use gradle 1.12 while developing the plugin and while using it. My dev environment for the plugin has two test modules and they have no messages like the real project.

My plugin has

```
@Override
public void apply(Project project) {
  [...]
  project.getExtensions().create("plugin", PluginTaskExtension.class, project);
}
```

The main problem is, that in my production environment the properties are empty and my tester have them. Where can be my mistake?

Comment: Does your Extension class (PluginTaskExtension) contain a appVersion property?

Comment: My PluginTaskExtension does have public void appVersion(String version) { this.mAppVersion = version; } - As I said, I tested the same plugin in my tester project/module.

Comment: I found my mistake. I was writing "var = value" instead of "var value".