# Custom Gradle Java based plugin is not working

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to implement a Gradle Java based plugin. I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664183/creating-a-gradle-custom-plugin-with-java) answer to do it.

**ROOT/plugin/src/main/java/com.test.plugin/ReleasePlugin.java**

```
public class ReleasePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.task("ggrelease");
    }

}
```

**ROOT/plugin/src/main/java/com.test.plugin/ReleaseTask.java**

```
public class GGReleaseTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    public void ggrelease() {
        System.out.println("Hello from ggrelease task");
    }
}
```

I can see the task in my plugin's consumer module:

[image]

But when I run it, I can't see the message. I have tried to throw `GradleException` instead of print a message, but it doesn't work. I get just `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`.

Comment: Have you tried running it from console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. You have to create the task and assign the class that implements the task:

```
public class ReleasePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getTasks().create("ggrelease", GGReleaseTask.class);
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
public class ReleasePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.task("ggrelease");
    }
}
```