# Custom Gradle Plugin cannot find it's own maven dependency

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

In my project, I want to include a gradle task that uses custom dependencies. 
To do that, I'm going to write a custom gradle plugin.

But when I start gradle, the following error is displayed:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'moduleUpdater'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.

Could not find org.example.plugin:MyJavaPlugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT.

Searched in the following locations:
         .../moduleUpdater/repo/org/example/plugin/MyJavaPlugin/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
         .../moduleUpdater/repo/org/example/plugin/MyJavaPlugin/1.0-SNAPSHOT/MyJavaPlugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
        .../moduleUpdater/repo/org/example/plugin/MyJavaPlugin/1.0-SNAPSHOT/MyJavaPlugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Required by:           
         :moduleUpdater:unspecified
```

The problem is that the maven dependency of the custom gradle plugin is not added to the main rootProject.

I used a tutorial just like:
[Creating a Gradle Custom Plugin with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664183/creating-a-gradle-custom-plugin-with-java)
and
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/gradle-custom-plugin.html

The following tutorial makes a project, just like it is on this git-repository:
https://github.com/rakeshcusat/Code4Reference/tree/master/GradleExample/custom-plugin-1

But if I try to run "gradle task" in the "user"-folder of this given repository, I still get the same message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'user'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.code4reference:code4ReferencePlugin:1.1-SNAPSHOT.
     Searched in the following locations:
         .../Code4Reference-master/GradleExample/custom-plugin-1/repo/com/code4reference/code4ReferencePlugin/1.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
         .../Code4Reference-master/GradleExample/custom-plugin-1/repo/com/code4reference/code4ReferencePlugin/1.1-SNAPSHOT/code4ReferencePlugin-1.1-20120816.164441-5.pom
         .../Code4Reference-master/GradleExample/custom-plugin-1/repo/com/code4reference/code4ReferencePlugin/1.1-SNAPSHOT/code4ReferencePlugin-1.1-20120816.164441-5.jar
     Required by:
         :user:unspecified
```

How can it tell gradle to automatically create the plugin's maven repository (using the same task)?

Comment: Please post your `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering with reference to the github link you posted, since we do not have your code.

The `user` project uses the plugin, but the plugin has to be built and deployed to `../repo` first before you can use it. go to `plugin` project first and run

```
gradle install
```

this builds the plugin and creates a maven repository in the folder `../repo`

Comment: please use the upvote button if you find this answer useful

Comment: thank you, this was exactly what I needed:
this command, together with the 
> gradle uploadArchives
command are needed to build and upload the plugin and build the root gradle project.

Is there also a possibility to include this process in another gradle task of the root project?